# using @value with PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I have properties file *report.properties* (\WEB-INF\classes\properties\report.properties) with entry :

```
reportTemplate = reports/report5.jrxml
```

and *applicationContext-reports.xml* (\WEB-INF\config\applicationContext-reports.xml) with entry:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location" value="classpath:properties/report.properties"/>
</bean>
```

*web.xml*:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/config/applicationContext-reports.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

In my controller I have:

```
private @Value("${reportTemplate}") String reportTemplatePath;
```

But when i print this to check its value as:

```
System.out.println("reportTemplatePath="+reportTemplatePath);
```

Instead of output:`reports/report5.jrxml` (taken from property file ) it gives `reportTemplatePath=${reportTemplate}`

**Edit:** Copied OP comment here for clarity and to show where the `System.out.println` is located.

```
@Controller
public class myController {
    private @Value("${reportTemplate}") String reportTemplatePath;
    // other field declarations... 

    @RequestMapping(value="report.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET) public String showReport() throws JRException{
        ...
        System.out.println("reportTemplatePath="+reportTemplatePath);
        ...
        return "report";
    }
}
```

Comment: At what point are you printing it? I suspect the println'ing is happening before `@Value` injection. Try adding a [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) method and outputting the private field there or a getter which you can be called after the class is constructed and wired up.

Comment: @andyb: Nopes! I m printing it after @Value declaration as : `@Controller
public class myController {
private @Value("${reportTemplate}") String reportTemplatePath;

// other field declarations...

 @RequestMapping(value="report.htm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showReport() throws JRException{
                ...
    System.out.println("reportTemplatePath="+reportTemplatePath);
    ...
    return "report";
        }
}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that `applicationContext-reports.xml` belongs to the root application context, whereas controller is declared in context of `DispatcherServlet`. If so, note that `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is configured at per-context basis, therefore you need to declare it in `...-servlet.xml` as well.